# Angular + Karma + CI/CD gitlab : Chrome and test running correctly in local but not in CI/CD job

Tags: angular, google-chrome, gitlab, karma-jasmine, cicd

I'm actually facing an issue with my test karma job for a CI/CD pipeline on gitlab binded to a kubernetes where my gitlab runner is setup.

Here is my issue:
When I run "ng test" with ChromeHeadless on my local machine, all the test are triggered correctly and I have all the output on my console BUT when I try to trigger my test with a CI/CD job nothing happen, even the Chrome process is killing before my test run.

I tried everything I found on the net like changing my karma.config.js file, change the customLauncher, changing the image I use during the job etc etc. set my lgo in Log_DEBUG for the output and other things....

I don't really know what to do next, I even saw "puppeteer" is mentionned several times so I tried it and nothing better happened

Could someone help me with this one please ? I'm running out of solution

Last output of my gitlab job :

```
22 02 2022 15:00:53.344:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inline plugin defining framework:jasmine, reporter:karma-jasmine.
22 02 2022 15:00:53.344:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inline plugin defining launcher:Chrome, launcher:ChromeHeadless, launcher:ChromeCanary, launcher:ChromeCanaryHeadless, launcher:Chromium, launcher:ChromiumHeadless, launcher:Dartium, test.
22 02 2022 15:00:53.344:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inline plugin defining reporter:kjhtml.
22 02 2022 15:00:53.344:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inline plugin defining preprocessor:coverage, reporter:coverage.
22 02 2022 15:00:53.345:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inline plugin defining framework:@angular-devkit/build-angular, reporter:@angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter, reporter:@angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter, middleware:@angular-devkit/build-angular--blocker, middleware:@angular-devkit/build-angular--fallback.
22 02 2022 15:00:53.345:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inline plugin defining launcher:ChromeHeadless.
22 02 2022 15:00:55.990:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
22 02 2022 15:00:55.991:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter
22 02 2022 15:00:55.992:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter (@angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter_color)
22 02 2022 15:00:55.992:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
22 02 2022 15:00:55.992:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter
22 02 2022 15:00:55.992:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter (@angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter_color)
22 02 2022 15:00:55.993:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
22 02 2022 15:00:56.106:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: kjhtml
22 02 2022 15:00:56.107:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: kjhtml (kjhtml_color)
22 02 2022 15:00:56.107:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
22 02 2022 15:00:56.154:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.13 server started at http://localhost:9876/
22 02 2022 15:00:56.154:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
22 02 2022 15:00:56.158:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
22 02 2022 15:00:56.159:DEBUG [launcher]: null -> BEING_CAPTURED
22 02 2022 15:00:56.159:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /tmp/karma-47542512
22 02 2022 15:00:56.159:DEBUG [launcher]: google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/karma-47542512 --enable-automation --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-device-discovery-notifications --headless --no-sandbox http://localhost:9876/?id=47542512
/scripts-711-48798/step_script: line 135:    76 Killed                  node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --watch=false
+ runner_script_trap
+ exit_code=1
+ out_json='{"command_exit_code": 1, "script": "/scripts-711-48798/step_script"}'
+ echo ''
+ echo '{"command_exit_code": 1, "script": "/scripts-711-48798/step_script"}'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
+ exit 0
+ set -eo pipefail
+ set +o noclobber
+ :
+ eval '$'\''rm'\'' "-f" "/builds/gitlab/Nantes/outils/gamingbyapside_front.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE"
'
++ rm -f /builds/gitlab/Nantes/outils/gamingbyapside_front.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
+ exit 0
+ runner_script_trap
+ exit_code=0
+ out_json='{"command_exit_code": 0, "script": "/scripts-711-48798/cleanup_file_variables"}'
+ echo ''
+ echo '{"command_exit_code": 0, "script": "/scripts-711-48798/cleanup_file_variables"}'
+ exit 0
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

karma.config.js :

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/gba'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    captureTimeout: 180000,
    browsers: ['Chrome','ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
    - install
    - test
    - build
    - deploy

install_dependencies:
    stage: install
    only:
        - master
        - tag
    script : 
        - echo "Install job only on master and tag"

lint:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Linting job is here BOY"

test-karma:
    variables:
        CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
    image : trion/ng-cli-karma
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Unit testing our angular app with karma baby"
        - npm ci
        - node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --watch=false

build:
    stage: build
    only:
        - master
        - tag
    script:
        - "I'm gonna build your app just for you, it will be 5$ ...."

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - master
        - tag
    script:
        - "I'm not like build job, i'll deploy your app for free, I know you are broke"
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "gba",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with something I would have thought would have been thoroughly 'solved' by now. Tried a dozen things, googled like crazy, but just can't get it to run the tests. I'm expecting there's an image out there that makes it just work, but can't find it. Frustrating.

Comment: Did you try the image without a custom chrome launcher configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at a similar problem for a while too. As pointed out by @Thomas in the comments to this question, I tried a custom chrome launcher. Turns out we were using a very old chrome version. This version was not even loading our code. Worth pointing out that this issues started when we upgraded one of our dependencies to typescript. Upgrading chrome to the latest version appears to have solved it for me.